# Create element and event (click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

My code:

```
<script>
        function abc(){
          for (var i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
          {
             var t = $('<li></li>').text(i);    
             $("ol").prepend(t);
          }
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("li").click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
          });
        });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body> 
  <button onclick = "abc()">asdf</button> 
  <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p> 
  <ol> 
    <li>Click me away!</li> 
    <li>Click me too!</li> 
  </ol>
</body>
```

Why when i click on the created (li) - it doesn't hide? 
How can i do it?

Comment: <body>
<button onclick = "abc()">btn</button>
<ol>
<li>Some text</li>
</ol>
</body>

Comment: When updating your question, please edit the question directly instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/b36VB/  Are you actually importing jQuery?  You seem to be trying to use it

Comment: @ben336: When editing a question, it is better form to abort when someone else has made an edit before you finish.

Comment: @JonathanWood Didn't get any messages about another edit.  Sorry if I overwrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when DOM is loaded there are no `<li>` elements added yet. You add them on click only.

There are several solutions here. One is to bind event directly to the created element:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $("<li></li>").text(i).on("click", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }).prependTo("ol");
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Xgr22/

Another way is to use event delegation:

```
$("ol").on("click", "li", function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Xgr22/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('ol').on('click','li',function(){
        $(this).hide();
      });
    });
```

This ensures that all 'li' elements fire the click handler when clicked, whether they are already created, or whether they are created later.

Comment: No need to delegate up to `document`, while `<ol>` is the nearest static parent.

Comment: And it doesn't ensure that "all 'li' elements get the click handler" - it ensures that when they are clicked, the handler is run. The 'li' elements do not have a click handler bound - just the original selector (`body` in this case)

Comment: Thanks for the comments VisioN and Ian. Modified answer.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to make sure it was understood how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

NB: Live is Depreciated!! this is how to do it pre jQuery 1.7

depending in the jQuery version you are using, if it's before 1.7 this will work

```
 <script>
    function abc(){
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
      {
         var t = $('<li></li>').text(i);    
         $("ol").prepend(t);
      }
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("li").live(function(){
        $(this).hide();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: So learn the new way and propose both. Deprecated things shouldn't be suggested when there's a new solution

Comment: someone already proposed the new way using "on" it clearly says this is for the older version, could it be clearer?

Comment: That's not our point. We can obviously see that you're specifying < 1.7 and that's great. I'm saying that for it to be a more complete answer (and maybe get votes), you should specify all possibilities you know, not just for specific jQuery versions. That's nice that someone else answered with the new way of doing this, but again, it would make your answer complete if you demonstrated how it could be done with modern versions of jQuery

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$('li').on('click', function () 
{
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.